# Como chamar a função do ng-blur de consulta antes de imprimir do PDF no AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um campo *CPF* *(text)* onde faço a consulta numa função `consultaNome` para **retornar** o *NOME* do *CPF* e tenho o botão **'Gerar PDF'** onde preciso **imprimir** o *CPF* e *NOME* que foi retornado.

Estou usando o **bg-blur** para realizar a consulta após deixar o **setfocus** do text.

#### CAMPO CPF NO FORM

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-if="vm.tipoPessoa === 'PF'">
    <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-blur="vm.carregarNomeSicli()" id="cpf" name="cpf" data-ng-model="vm.cpfcnpj" class="form-control input-sm" />
    <div data-ng-if="!vm.isValidoValor()">
        <em style="color: red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></em>
        <span style="color: red;">{{vm.messageService.getN('MN019')}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### BOTÃO GERAR PDF

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <button id="imprime" type="button" data-ng-click="PDF()" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></i> <span>Gerar PDF</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

#### O PROBLEMA:

Quando **altero** o *CPF* sem sair do **setfocus** e clico direto no botão **'Gerar PDF'** está acionando a impressão antes de retornar o *NOME* do novo *CPF*.

Estou buscando uma solução onde posso **acionar antes** a consulta pra só depois imprimir... Algum time ou refatoração do processo para imprimir sempre após a execução da consulta.

```
function imprimePDF() {
   $scope.PDF = function() {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de executar o código que imprime o PDF, você pode chamar o método carregarNomeSicli(). Desta forma, ele executará o método carregarNomeSicli(), depois a funcionalidade de imprimir PDF